# How to use ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor API in Delphi 6?

Tags: security, delphi, pipe, named

I am creating named pipe to communicate between two applications, one in Delphi 6 and the other in VC++. I am trying to give Full control to Administrators group using ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor. However, the compiler throws an error: Undeclared identifier 'ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor'.

I am looking for a working code sample that uses the above API.

This is how my code looks like:

```
uses
  Classes, Windows, SysUtils, AccCtrl, AclApi, WinTypes, WorkerThread;

function TPipeServer.GenerateSecurityAttributes() : Boolean;

var
  strSD           : string;
  PCharSD         : PChar;
  m_SA               : PSecurityAttributes;

begin
  ...
  strSD := 'A;OICI;GA;;;BA';
  PCharSD := StrAlloc(Length(strSD) + 1);
  StrPCopy(PCharSD, strSD);

  m_SA.nLength := SizeOf(m_SA);
  m_SA.bInheritHandle := False;
  ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
        'A;OICI;GA;;;BA',    //discretionary ACL to allow FULL access for Administrators group
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        m_SA.lpSecurityDescriptor,
        nil
      );
...
```

Comment: Don't dynamically allocate the string. Just use `PChar(strSD)`. You don't appear to allocate a record. Don't declare a pointer to the record. Declare a variable of record type. Then pass its address. Your SizeOf is wrong. You used the size of a pointer.

Comment: Anyway I've closed this as a duplicate of the question that you've clearly already seen. My answer there has code that works. You just didn't manage to copy that code correctly, and somehow introduced mistakes that weren't in the original.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I haven't taken the entire code to the project, but I have it in a temp file. But my concern is -- Delphi 6 compiler throwing an error - "Undeclared identifier ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor " for the API. Am I missing something in the "uses" section? Once this is resolved, I will eventually take the entire code posted by you.

Comment: You should have said that in the question.

Comment: You need this: `function ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
  StringSecurityDescriptor: PChar;
  StringSDRevision: DWORD;
  var SecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  SecurityDescriptorSize: PULONG
): BOOL; stdcall;` in the interface section of a unit

Comment: And then in the implementation section of the same unit you need `function ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor; external advapi32 name 'ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorA';`

Comment: Or just do some websearch. For instance, I search on the function name and delphi and came across a unit named JwaSddl that has the declaration.

Comment: Yes I got the unit JwaSddl which has the definition for the API. I will implement this. Thank you.